# Adding formControlName in Angular breaks "value" in input control

Tags: angular

I have a form and am trying to figure out why as soon as I add the attribute "formControlName" value stops rendering. I ended up boiling things down to a very simple example:

This:

```
<mat-form-field [style.width.px]=400>
    <mat-label>Port Redirects</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
</mat-form-field>
```

will render Sushi as expected:

[image]

However as soon as you add formControlName like this:

```
<mat-form-field [style.width.px]=400>
    <mat-label>Port Redirects</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="port_list" placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
</mat-form-field>
```

the value just up and disappears:

[image]

The [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview) says this is the way to do it so I'm at a loss as to why adding formControlName breaks things. Aside from the `value` field not working correctly, the form is otherwise just fine. Does everything I would expect it to. Is there a trick I'm missing?

Comment: You are trying to have angular reactive form, which works as like mentioned here https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#grouping-form-controls

Comment: I'm familiar - are they mutually exclusive? Can I not set a default value like I normally would when I use reactive forms?

Comment: ```formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive``` .. Take a look at the stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-p6usms .. Here the value can be set also you can change but it won't store into the control for which you need to make a formGroup and set the formcontrol in ```ts``` file.. But as you are familiar I hope you know that steps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you use any `FormControl` directive on an element, you should set its value using the directive instead of the `value` attribute. This is true for Reactive and Template-driven forms.

In that case you can do:

```js
_form = new FormGroup({
 port_list: new FormControl();
});

ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => 
    this._form.patchValue({port_list: 'Sushi'}));
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma622074656433166)

Notice that if you use the two approaches (set the `value` attribute and the form control), during initialization, `value` is set later, so it overrides the control value in the HTML element and doesn't update the form control value itself (likely a bug in the component). That's why I used a `setTimeout`: just to schedule the control setting value statement to be executed in the next turn of the event loop.